# Firefox misspelling all words since version 61

Tags: debian, firefox, spell-checking, hunspell

On my Debian 9 with Firefox 61 every word is marked as misspelled, except numbers (right now, currently as I'm typing).

Things I've tried:

1. Remove en-US dictionary and return it (Had to hard delete the files, as a simple removal of the extension did not remove files or menu option).
2. Add a second dictionary - it added them in the language menu and extensions tab but I don't see the files  at `/usr/lib/firefox/dictionaries/`. I tried this both through the addons and preferences.
3. Remove firefox (`sudo apt-get remove firefox firefox-esr chromium` to make sure no alternative is installed) and install again.
4. Clear data (all of it).
5. Delete `~/.mozilla/firefox/*`.

None of the above works. I noticed removing/installing dictionaries from the extension page in `firefox` does not affect the actual dictionary folder, even though the extension appears and the select language menu updates.

How do I get spell check to work?

Pardon any spelling mistakes.

Comment: Try this solution ..
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-use-firefox-spell-checker
I hope it’s work.

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to use the spell-check, the stuff above was to try and fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Debian's latest update (61.0-2) has resolved this. The [changelog](http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/f/firefox/firefox_61.0-2_changelog) says they've stopped compiling FF with the system's 'hunspell' package.